# Logging selenium for webdriver

Tags: java, logging, selenium, webdriver

Does any one use [loggingselenium](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/) for webdriber? I am trying to create a nice HTML formatted report which will includes stack trace of a failed tests including a screen shot. Loggingselenium is the best library for the porpose as i explained above. I am using maven and [surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/) for my project and I need to use logging selenium for my project which was done using webdriver. or find out other solution which will help me to do the same thing. As I am using junit for my tests, i want something like [this](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/samples/sampleResultJunitAssertionFailed.html).Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This actually looks like the best solution for your case. I used other tools that provide some logging with error stacks such as cucumber, jbehave or thucydides however they are a little bit different. So given a quick look your solution based on loggingselenium looks rather good.

Comment: Jenkins is also amazing at keeping test results. You can have screenshots there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [QAF formerly ISFW](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/). It has great logging and [reporting](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html) features as well as some design concepts especially for web functional test automation using selenium 1 or 2.  you can read below useful blogs:
[About ISFW](http://blog.infostretch.com/806)
[FAQ](http://blog.infostretch.com/isfw-faq)